# Cannot execute tests using Mtest.py in MonetDB

Tags: monetdb

I am currently trying to get going with developing additional functionality for the MonetDB DBMS. I have been reading through the code and tried to debug the code using **VSCODE** which actually works fine. However, I encountered difficulties when trying to run tests that are already present in the repo using `Mtest.py`.

To come to the current point, I have forked the latest version of **MonetDB (11.40.0)** and proceeded with installing it on my **ubuntu 20.04** by following the shipped debian documentation:

```
CONFIGURE_OPTIONS="-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DASSERT=ON -DSTRICT=ON"
cd build
cmake $CONFIGURE_OPTIONS
cmake --build .
cmake --build . --target install
```

The above statements install the applications in the default location. I have also tried to alter the installation direction using `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` flag. However, this lead to the same results and problems running the tests.

For running specific test cases I have tried the following two thing:

- cmake: `cmake --build . --target mtest`
- Mtest.py: `Mtest.py sql/test/Tests/`

Both attempts lead to the same console output:

```
Perl available, but MonetDB driver or DBI module not available
abort: there is no Mercurial repository here (.hg not found)
cannot write timeout message mserver5 --debug=10 --set gdk_nr_threads=0 --set mapi_listenaddr=all --set mapi_port=30201 --set mapi_usock=/var/tmp/mtest-16710/.s.monetdb.30201 --forcemito --dbpath=/usr/local/var/MonetDB/mTests

Mtest.py:  ERROR:  No output from mserver5 when checking for Bits, Modules & Threads!?
```

It states that the started `mserver5` instance is not responding properly somehow. I have currently no clue how to tackle this issue. Can anyone tell me if I might missed out on something?

I have checked the build flags and the corresponding **TESTING** flag is set on default. Is there anything I messed up with **mserver5** or I might have to configure separately?

Looking forward to hearing from you,
Martin

Comment: The message about `Bits, Modules & Threads` is usually a sign of being unable to start `mserver5`. The first step in debugging this is to figure out why. Please try to run mserver manually, e.g., `mserver5 --dbpath=/tmp/dummydb` and see what the exact error message is.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason for my issue with running MonetDB's tests. Thanks to @Joeri van Ruth for making playing around with `mserver5` application.

The problem was that I commented in the definition of `_SQL_COMPILE` in the file `sql_execute.sql` in order to view the generated MAL code and other debug output generated along compilation. The problem with this is that it calls `mnstr_printf` and is printing to `stdout`. This debug output to somehow interferes the required communication and `mserver5` cannot respond correctly.